# Access to user's email

Tags: python, django

I want to put the email of user in my model Article.

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Article(models.Model):

    #auteur
    email = models.ForeignKey(User.email, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #titre
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title_en = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subtitle_en = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written has no sense. You have to keep a ForeignKey on the user, and then access to his email through `user.email`:

```
class Article(models.Model):

    #auteur
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    #titre
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title_en = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subtitle_en = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then, `Article.user.username` (or `self.user.username` inside an `Article` method) gives you the name and `Article.user.email` the e-mail.

#### Some explanations

In Django, you can create `ForeignKey` only on Model object, and not object field. This will be translate in SQL as a classic reference between tables. (If you check your Article SQL database, you'll see a `user_id` field. This field will contains the ID of the user, extract from the `auth_user` table, which created the Article.

Comment: Thank you, great answer with explanations!